# Async Operations when using AFNetworking

Tags: afnetworking

I was trying to use AFNetworking Framework to test network connectivity to website "www.abc.org"

Code:

```
- (void)connect
{
    NSLog(@"1");
    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"2");

        switch (status) {
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
            {
                NSLog(@"3");

                AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
                manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
                manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = self.timeoutAccumulator; // timeout
                manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

                [manager GET:@"http://www.abc.org/" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                    NSLog(@"4");

                } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                }];
            }
                break;

            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            default:
                break;
        }
    }];

    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] stopMonitoring];
    NSLog(@"5");
}
```

The console output is:

1

5

2

3

4

It looks like the Operations are Async. How can I make the operations in the main queue, or the main thread. so the 2nd operation will wait for the 1st operation to complete. What I want is the Output in the order of:

1

2

3

4

5

Comment: Don't do networking operations in the main queue.  If you have dependent operations, you can make `AFHTTPRequestOperation`s dependent on each other (they are `NSOperation` subclasses). Or, you could make the dependent network request in the completion block of the independent request.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is using block with completion.